# How can I typeset a bibkey with &?

Tags: catcodes

1. I would like to typeset a catalog of all my BibTeX entries.
2. I have been using `&` in many `bibkey`'s such as `Author&Editor:2000`.
3. But I cannot `\catcode38=12` globally.

My question is: how can I typeset such a `bibkey` both in a section heading, and in the table of contents, and also cite it?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

With:

```
\newcommand\entry[1]{%
 \catcode38=12\relax
 \section{#1}
 \fullcite{#1}}

\entry{Author&Editor:2000}
```

But I get:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@book{Author&Editor:2000, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 0}, year={2000}}
@book{Author&Editor:2001, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 1}, year={2001}}
@book{Author&Editor:2002, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 2}, year={2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\entry[1]{%
 \catcode38=12\relax
 \section{#1}
 \fullcite{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\entry{Author&Editor:2000}
\entry{Author&Editor:2001}
\entry{Author&Editor:2002}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to change category codes; we just need a robust version of `\detokenize`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@book{Author&Editor:2000, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 0}, year={2000}}
@book{Author&Editor:2001, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 1}, year={2001}}
@book{Author&Editor:2002, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 2}, year={2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\entry[1]{%
 \section{\keep{#1}}%
 \fullcite{#1}}
%%% \newrobustcmd is from etoolbox, loaded by biblatex
\newrobustcmd{\keep}[1]{\detokenize{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\entry{Author&Editor:2000}
\entry{Author&Editor:2001}
\entry{Author&Editor:2002}

\end{document}
```

Note that you have to add the extension in `\addbibresource{foo.bib}`

Comment: Even if this works is it good practise to do it? (And whats `biker` in your comment …?)

Comment: @Tobi I'd like to start going out with my motorbike, but the weather is still bad. :( This should explain the *lapsus calami*. Regarding the question, I don't think it's good practice, if you want my opinion. :) But this may come handy in different situations.

Answer (score 6):

Changing catcodes mid document is a really bad idea, it will break stuff, but if you are going to do it, you need to get the timing right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@book{Author&Editor:2000, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 0}, year={2000}}
@book{Author&Editor:2001, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 1}, year={2001}}
@book{Author&Editor:2002, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 2}, year={2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\entry{\bgroup\catcode`\&=12 \xentry}
\newcommand\xentry[1]{\egroup
 \section{#1}%
 \fullcite{#1}}

\begin{document}

{\catcode`\&=12 \tableofcontents}

\entry{Author&Editor:2000}
\entry{Author&Editor:2001}
\entry{Author&Editor:2002}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I typeset such a bibkey

I'm pretty sure you can't do that as `&` will always be interpreted as Alignment Character *before* you can change it.

But you can use `\&`. See also your corrected (and now working) example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@book{Author\&Editor:2000, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 0}, year={2000}}
@book{Author\&Editor:2001, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 1}, year={2001}}
@book{Author\&Editor:2002, author={Author}, editor={Editor}, title={Title 2}, year={2002}}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\entry[1]{%
 \catcode38=12\relax
 \section{#1}
 \fullcite{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\entry{Author\&Editor:2000}
\entry{Author\&Editor:2001}
\entry{Author\&Editor:2002}

\end{document}
```

Regards,
Nick

Comment: Did you try it? I did, and it doesn't work. By the way, what's the purpose of the category code change?